# Cannot write to cifs share with SMB/Samba between 2 linux machines

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

As `user1` (primary group `root`) on `server1` (Linux) I am able to write files to `/tmp`.

The permissions are:

```
drwxrwxrwt  19 root              root  4096 Jan  3 11:04 ./
```

When I mount (cifs) `server1` using `usern=user1` on `server2` (Linux) I am unable to write any files.

```
user2@server2$ echo hello >> /mnt/server1/tmp/foo
-bash: /mnt/server2/tmp/foo: Permission denied
```

However, I am able to write files from a Windows client when I connect with `user1`!

### /etc/samba/smb.conf on server1

```
[root]
        comment = Root
        available = yes
        path = /
        write list = root user1 @root
        read only = no
        browsable = yes
        public = yes
        writable = yes
```

### /etc/fstab on server2

```
//server1/root    /mnt/server1   cifs    user=user1,password=***,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770,nounix    ,uid=0,gid=0,forceuid,forcegid
```

I have tried with/without the `uid=0,gid=0,forceuid,forcegid` options as well as the mode and `nounix` options.

From `server2`I can list files in `/mnt/server1/tmp` and see files I created locally on `server1`. I don't see any permissions errors in the logs `/var/log/*`.

Where/how can I diagnose the issue?

---

### UPDATE

I am able to write to the share from server2 as root. This is really strange as I would think server1 would not trust that `root` from `server2` is the same `root` on `server1`.

Comment: Why `uid=0,gid=0`? This would not enforce a valid user account. Have you tried passing credentials in the mount statement?

Comment: It was a blind attempt - the result is the same without this setting.

Comment: As a workaround (which works) I put `forceuser=user1` in the smb.conf but this is not really what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solvable by providing the owner of the share in the mount command.
Try options :

```
uid=user1,gid=user1,username=user1
```